# Redundancy without central control point?

Tags: concurrency, erlang, distribution

If it possible to provide a service to multiple clients whereby if the server providing this service goes down, another one takes it's place- without some sort of centralised "control" which detects whether the main server has gone down and to redirect the clients to the new server?

Is it possible to do without having a centralised interface/gateway?

In other words, its a bit like asking can you design a node balancer without having a centralised control to direct clients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is a general overview to high availability for networked applications, not specific to Erlang. I don't know too much about what is available in the OTP framework yet because I am new to the language.

---

There are a few different problems here:

1. Client connection must be moved to the backup machine
2. The session may contain state data
3. How to detect a crash

**Problem 1 - Moving client connection**
This may be solved in many different ways and on different layers of the network architecture. The easiest thing is to code it right into the client, so that when a connection is lost it reconnects to another machine.

If you need network transparency you may use some technology to sync TCP states between different machines and then reroute all traffic to the new machine, which may be *entirely* invisible for the client. This is much harder to do than the first suggestion.

I'm sure there are lots of things to do in-between these two.

**Problem 2 - State data**
You obviously need to transfer the session state from the crashed machine unto the backup machine. This is really hard to do in a reliable way and you may lose the last few transactions because the crashed machine may not be able to send the last state before the crash. You can use a synchronized call in this way to be *really* sure about not losing state:

1. Transaction/message comes from the client into the main machine.
2. Main machine updates some state.
3. New state is sent to backup machine.
4. Backup machine confirms arrival of the new state.
5. Main machine confirms success to the client.

This may potentially be expensive (or at least not responsive enough) in some scenarios since you depend on the backup machine and the connection to it, including latency, before even confirming anything to the client. To make it perform better you can let the client check with the backup machine upon connection what transactions it received and then resend the lost ones, making it the client's responsibility to queue the work.

**Problem 3 - Detecting a crash**
This is an interesting problem because a crash is not always well-defined. Did something really crash? Consider a network program that closes the connection between the client and server, but both are still up and connected to the network. Or worse, makes the client disconnect from the server without the server noticing. Here are some questions to think about:

- Should the client connect to the backup machine?
- What if the main server updates some state and send it to the backup machine while the backup have the real client connected - will there be a data race?
- Can both the main and backup machine be up at the same time or do you need to shut down work on one of them and move all sessions?
- Do you need some sort of authority on this matter, some protocol to decide which one is *master* and which one is *slave*? Who is that authority? How do you decentralise it?
- What if your nodes loses their connection between them but both continue to work as expected (called *network partitioning*)?

Comment: Hi, session state isn;t what I am worried about. I just cannot see how you can allocate new servers to clients, unless you have some sort of centralised control? Its like having a node balancer.... yet the balancer isn't in one place.... how could it work unless the balancer knew everything which was going on?

Comment: Send a list of servers to the client upon connection. If the server crashes, let the client reconnect to another machine.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you are not giving much information about the "service" you are asking about, so I'll answer in a *generic* way.

For the first part of my answer, I'll assume you are talking about a "centralized interface/gateway" involving ip addresses. For this, there's CARP (Common Address Redundancy Protocol), quoted from the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Address_Redundancy_Protocol):

> The Common Address Redundancy Protocol or CARP is a protocol which
> allows multiple hosts on the same local network to share a set of IP
> addresses. Its primary purpose is to provide failover redundancy,
> especially when used with firewalls and routers. In some
> configurations CARP can also provide load balancing functionality. It
> is a free, non patent-encumbered alternative to Cisco's HSRP. CARP is
> mostly implemented in BSD operating systems.

Quoting the netbsd's "[Introduction to CARP](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-carp.html)":

> CARP works by allowing a group of hosts on the same network segment to
> share an IP address. This group of hosts is referred to as a
> "redundancy group". The redundancy group is assigned an IP address
> that is shared amongst the group members. Within the group, one host
> is designated the "master" and the rest as "backups". The master host
> is the one that currently "holds" the shared IP; it responds to any
> traffic or ARP requests directed towards it. Each host may belong to
> more than one redundancy group at a time.

This might solve your question at the network level, by having the slaves takeover the ip address in order, without a single point of failure.

Now, for the second part of the answer (the application level), with distributed erlang, you can have several nodes (a cluster) that will give you fault tolerance and redundancy (so you would not use ip addresses here, but "distributed erlang" -a cluster of erlang nodes- instead).

You would have lots of nodes lying around with your [Distributed Applciation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/distributed_applications.html) started, and your application resource file would contain a list of nodes (ordered) where the application can be run.

[Distributed erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) will control which of the nodes is "the master" and will automagically start and stop your application in the different nodes, as they go up and down.

Quoting (as less as possible) from http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/distributed_applications.html:

> In a distributed system with several Erlang nodes, there may be a need
> to control applications in a distributed manner. If the node, where a
> certain application is running, goes down, the application should be
> restarted at another node.
>
> The application will be started at the first node, specified by the
> distributed configuration parameter, which is up and running. The
> application is started as usual.
>
> For distribution of application control to work properly, the nodes
> where a distributed application may run must contact each other and
> negotiate where to start the application.
>
> When started, the node will wait for all nodes specified by
> sync_nodes_mandatory and sync_nodes_optional to come up. When all
> nodes have come up, or when all mandatory nodes have come up and the
> time specified by sync_nodes_timeout has elapsed, all applications
> will be started. If not all mandatory nodes have come up, the node
> will terminate.
>
> If the node where the application is running goes down, the
> application is restarted (after the specified timeout) at the first
> node, specified by the distributed configuration parameter, which is
> up and running. This is called a failover

distributed = [{Application, [Timeout,] NodeDesc}]

> If a node is started, which has higher priority according to
> distributed, than the node where a distributed application is
> currently running, the application will be restarted at the new node
> and stopped at the old node. This is called a takeover.

Ok, that was meant as a general overview, since it can be a long topic :)

For the specific details, it is highly recommended to read the [Distributed OTP Applications](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distributed-otp-applications) chapter for [learnyousomeerlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com) (and of course the previous link:  http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/distributed_applications.html)

Also, your "service" might depend on other external systems like databases, so you should consider fault tolerance and redundancy there, too. The whole architecture needs to be fault tolerance and distributed for "the service" to work in this way.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, this does help but do you mind if I give you more details. For a distributed erlang application, is it possible to provide an architecture whereby a client connects to a server and if that server goes down, another replaces it, without having a centralised entity that controls the current server node? I cannot see how it can be done- but apparently it can be. I cannot see how it can be implemented without having a centralised entity that detects the server crashes and tells the client the next server to use??

Comment: @Porcupine Hi! For the network stuff (the client "connecting" to a server), you can use CARP (will depend on a number of things),having lots of nodes sharing the IP address. Once the connection is made to an erlang node,the other stuff is done automagically by distributed erlang. Just use your application as normal (I'm assuming there's no network interruption between your erlang nodes, and you just want to handle hw failures). see the links I posted (above all, the link to the Distributed OTP Applications of learnyousomeerlang, it has a detailed discussion and examples about distributed apps)

Answer (score 1):

See Google's paper ["Chubby lock server" (PDF)](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//archive/chubby-osdi06.pdf) and ["Paxos made live" (PDF)](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/cs262/Readings/paxosmadelive.pdf) to get an idea.

Briefly,this solution involves using a consensus protocol to elect a master among a group of servers that handles all the requests. If the master fails, the protocol is used again to elect the next master.

Also, see [gen_leader](https://github.com/abecciu/gen_leader_revival) for an example in leader election which works with detecting failures and transferring service ownership.